# Class not found exception . dispatcher servlet unable to find HSSFWorkBook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I Have added poi-ooxml dependency in pom.xml still I am getting an error i.e.  Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook

Comment: That class should probably be in the main POI jar, which would be your *main* dependency *along with* poi-xml